# What is a "center loss"?

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, computer-vision, objective-functions, face-recognition

I have seen that a *center loss* is beneficial in computer vision, especially in face recognition. I have tried to understand this concept from the following material

1. [A Discriminative Feature Learning Approach for Deep Face Recognition](https://ydwen.github.io/papers/WenECCV16.pdf)
2. https://www.slideshare.net/JisungDavidKim/center-loss-for-face-recognition

However, I could not understand the concept clearly. If someone can explain with the help of an example, that would be appreciated.